# Create PerOwinContext In .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, owin

How can I create owin context like this in .net Core So that I can use User and Role manager?

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        //app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);

        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);


   }
```

and use in Controller like

```
  private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;

    public UsersAdminController()
    {
    }

    public UsersAdminController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
        RoleManager = roleManager;
    }


  public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _signInManager = value;
        }
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get

        {
     //GetOwinContext is not available in .Net Core
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

     public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _roleManager = value;
        }
    }
```

I have tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-3.0) but did'nt get desired results.

Answer (score 0):

That's code for ASP.NET MVC 5, *not* Core. Despite having "ASP.NET" in both names, these are *completely different frameworks*.

In Core, services like `UserManager<TUser>` are request-scoped, which is functionally the same as "per OWIN context". However, Identity is different in ASP.NET Core, so things like `ApplicationSignInManager` no longer apply. You need to refer to the docs and implement auth as it's supposed to be done in ASP.NET Core.